# extjs classic sandbox vs classic theme

Tags: javascript, extjs, themes

Does anyone know what is the difference between ***ExtJS*** `classic sandbox` vs `classic` theme?

I found `classic sandbox` theme in ***examples/resources/*** `folder` but the toolbar at the top-right corner only has 4 options (access, classic, gray, Neptune). How can I set it to have this fifth option if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sandbox sounds like a sort of playground but I never looked at it (*sidenote*: sanbox uses a `x4` prefix while default is using `x`). Anyway you can add it or any other theme like so

In case of the sandbox we have to tweak because the loader has a static name prefix `ext-all`. So rename the following files.

```
resources/css/ext-sandbox.css
resources/css/ext-sandbox-debug.css
```

to

```
resources/css/ext-all-sandbox.css
resources/css/ext-all-sandbox-debug.css
```

after that open

```
examples/shared/options-toolbar.js
```

and the following component definition

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    rtl: false,
    width: 170,
    labelWidth: 50,
    fieldLabel: 'Theme',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'value',
    labelStyle: 'cursor:move;',
    margin: '0 10 0 0',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         fields: ['value', 'name'],
         data : [
             { value: 'access', name: 'Accessibility' },
             { value: 'classic', name: 'Classic' },
             { value: 'gray', name: 'Gray' },
             { value: 'neptune', name: 'Neptune' }
         ]
    }),
/....
```

add { value: 'sandbox', name: 'Classic Sandbox' } to the data array that it looks like

```
data : [
    { value: 'access', name: 'Accessibility' },
    { value: 'classic', name: 'Classic' },
    { value: 'gray', name: 'Gray' },
    { value: 'neptune', name: 'Neptune' },
    { value: 'sandbox', name: 'Classic Sandbox' } // new line
]
```

open `examples/themes/themes.js` and find `function getSizing(id)`

add the sizing based on the new theme. In case of the sandbox we would change

```
if (theme == 'gray') {
```

to

```
if (theme == 'gray' || theme == 'sandbox') {
```

That's it. Now you can choose it from the options combo and it will get loaded.